# Fusing power injected LEDs from both sides

Tags: led, fuses, low-voltage, ws2812b

I am involved on a project where we will be installing thousands of LEDs (WS2812B Addressable strips) on the floor. I have a question about about fusing and if there is a more efficient way to go about things.

This is how I'm currently wiring things. Excuse my wiring pseudo-diagram. Assume each LED is a full LED strip and that I am power injecting. This works fine but will require three times as many wires so I wonder if there is a more efficient way to wire this.

[image: Normal Fusing]
[image]

What I'm wondering is if I can wire things like this and still have fuse protection. The reason is that each end of the floor is 15 to 20 feet apart and I need to inject power on each end.

[image]
[image]
I understand that setting fuses up like this could potentially double up the circuit's maximum current, given an even electricity flow. Given the resistance of the LEDs and the changing nature of animation, the current draw on each end of the LED strips will fluctuate.

Is there a scenario where I can lower my fuses' capacity or change up my wiring to make things cleaner to lay out.

Right now, I'm fusing at every 350 or so LEDs and we will be laying down thousands.

I'm mostly looking for ways to optimize wiring.

Comment: Are you implying that putting a fuse in the supply and return lines will double the amount of current you can pass through the wire?  There are no shortcuts when it comes to high current; either bump up the voltage or get ready to pay for copper.

Comment: Why do all of the return wires from your LEDs go back to the positive side of the 5V supply and nothing goes to the negative side? The way you've drawn it nothing will work ...

Comment: I think they're asking about connecting power at both ends of a 20' long strip of LEDs.  The datasheet I can find for the WS2812B bare module doesn't list current draw anywhere.  I think it'll come down to what's the longest length of whichever assembled strip can be powered from one end.  Applying power and fusing from both ends sounds like a recipe for nuisance trips or melted traces.

Comment: @vir those are the addressable LED strips ... power should be applied from both ends of the strip to prevent fadeout at the far end ... the power could be applied in the middle also to ensure even brightness

Comment: @jsotola Yes to addressable LED strips, I added some Paint drawings to hopefully help clarify. I know my Wrong LED schematic draws would be confusing, apologies thanks for the help so far. As for LED I'm going off a .033 amp per Led calculation I saw for my uses case. Each full strip is 15 LEDs 16feet in length.

What I am hearing is any power injection should happen on the same fuse and introducing another fuse on the other end is asking for trouble.  Thoughts?

Comment: The fuse is to protect the wire, not the load. Given a short circuit or overload condition, the fuse ensures the wire will not see excessive current that would cause the insulation to fail and possibly create a fire or electrocution hazard.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a fuse on the high side (the 5V side) the ground will be the same potential so you don't need a fuse on that end. If ground touches something else it will not transfer much current.

You also need to fuse the end closest to the supply on each string of LED's, putting in fuses between strings won't be safer or protect anything because the fuse with the most current will be the most upstream fuse and it will blow first.

Make sure the first fuse is rated for more than all of the max combined current of the loads (LED strings) downstream. (A 2A load would need more than 2.5A fuse, you don't want a fuse at exactly 2A or it will blow all the time when the LED's reach their max current of 2A)

Don't exceed the max rating of the LED strips, lets say the max current is 6A and each string is 2A, then you could only link up 3 strings in series.

If connecting strings in parallel then they should have a fuse for each string.

Comment: Methinks your final paragraph has confused "series" with "parallel"