# Power injecting LEDs with a separate fuse from both sides?

Tags: power-supply, led, led-strip, fuses

This is in reference to this question. [Fusing power injected LEDs from both sides](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641960/fusing-power-injected-leds-from-both-sides)

Reposting for Clarity

I am involved on a project where we will be installing thousands of LEDs (WS2812B Addressable strips) on the floor. LED Strips

[image]
I have a question about about fusing and if there is a more efficient way to go about things.

Am I able to power inject in on both ends of the led strip and use a sperate fuse on each end.

[image]

My current understanding from my previous question is that this could cause an unstable circuit, nuisance trips and that I would be doubling up the fuses potential uninentially.

The reason I am hoping to do it this way is so I can create a power bus to fuse off of, that way I can have much cleaner wiring. My current design (Not pictured above) Requires 12 trips back to the power source per side of the floor. So even fuse placement ideas would be helpful.

I'm fusing at every 350 or so LEDs and we will lay down over 4000 on this layer. Here is a diagram of the project.

[image]
I'm mostly looking for ways to optimize wiring for powering. I apricate the help. If the answer is nope lay down the wire then that's the plan.

Comment: you asked this before ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641960/fusing-power-injected-leds-from-both-sides

Comment: As mentioned, this is a clarifying repost. The previous post timed out and the way I initially asked the question was confusing. I do apricate your help from before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the whole lot is running off one big power supply.

Using multiple fuses in parallel feeding the same LEDs doesn't really achieve anything useful.  If one fuse blows for any reason, it will increase the load on the others, and you will get a cascading failure until all the fuses have blown.

Either use one big fuse rated for the whole lot, or split the LEDs into several separately fused blocks, still with one fuse per block.  There's nothing stopping you from splitting the wiring to feed both ends, or even multiple points, after a fuse.

---

It's worth thinking about what the fuses are actually protecting.  The power supply?  The wiring?  It's probably not providing any meaningful protection to the LEDs.  Until you know what the fuses are for, it's difficult to say where they should be.

Comment: It will be running off of two 5v 60amp power supplies. The power supplies will be on separate circuits. 2000 Pixels each.

The fusing is to protect the LED wiring in case of a short circuit.  The worry is protecting against a fire.  The strips are equivalent to about 20 gauge wire. My thinking is if I place a fuse at every 350 or so Pixels I'm covered. Max draw(Much higher than actual operation ) is 33ma per Pixel  * 350 * 0.8 (Brightness Limiter) Gets my 9.24amp so id place a 10amp fuse.

Am I overengineering this? Could I get away with less fusing if Im only worried about fire proection?

Comment: A 10A fuse on a 9.24 circuit is cutting things a bit close for comfort. You have a wire between the power supply and the led strip - that is what the fuse should be protecting. If the Ampacity ofcthe wire is 10A and you run 9.24A through it, then choose a heavier gauge wire. Apart from protecting the wire from overheating, what else do you expect the fuse to do?

Comment: It's a good point, I'll pull down the power intensity of the LEDs a bit to give the 10amp fuse a bit more buffer.  The wire in this instance is the strip itself and I cant beef up the gauge of it.
Really that's it, I don't want the wires to overheat. The Bundle of wires coming back to circuit is cumbersome but looks like that's just the case when dealing with this quantity of LED's

Comment: I'm going to mark this correct. Although not the solution I was looking for It got me to re assess the way I was thinking about the fusing. Thanks for looking into this everyone.